# In Python I have a barcode scanner input without using the enter key to submit the scan

Tags: python, usb

I have a Honeywell ascii barcode scanner I want the user to scan the code and the code to go directly into a string variable with just triggering the scanner.

```
ipAddress = '192.168.0.50'
tagName = 'RTA_Read'
scan = ""
choice = 1


while choice == 1:
    scan = str(input('Please Scan\n'))
    with PLC(ipAddress) as comm:
        ret = comm.Write(tagName, scan)
        print(f"Tag reqested is: {ret.TagName}")
        print(f"Read Status is: {ret.Status}")
        print(f"The tag value is: {ret.Value}")
```

I expected to squeeze the trigger on the scanner and the data would populate the string and be written directly to the PLC. What is happening is I squeeze the trigger and then i have to hit the return key on the keyboard to move the string data to the PLC using pylogix.

Comment: `input()` will freeze forever unless you press Enter. You need something that is continuously checking if the scan has been done; you have explicitly made your code only check after you press enter. Also, the returned value of `input()` is already a `str`, so there's no need to convert it.

Comment: https://sps-support.honeywell.com/s/article/How-to-program-an-automatic-ENTER-on-Honeywell-Metrologic-Intermec-Scanners

Comment: Thank you ! very new to python what could I use instead of input() to get the string automatically?

Comment: Configure your scanner to end its output with a carriage return.

Comment: Thanks everyone ! I followed the article that Martheen shared the link to and everything is working great! I just scanned a barcode on the Honeywell site that makes my scanner use the carriage return afer trigger i really appreciate everyone's time .